# Regex filtering of messages in SNS

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services

Is there a way to filter messages based on **Regex** or substring in AWS *SNS*?

[AWS Documentation for filtering messages](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html) mentions three types of filtering for strings:

- Exact matching (whitelisting)
- Anything-but matching (blacklisting)
- Prefix matching

I want to filter out messages based on substrings in the messages, for example

I have a S3 event that sends a message to SNS when a new object is added to S3, the contents of the message are as below:

```
{
    "Records": [
        {
            "s3": {
                "bucket": {
                    "name": "images-bucket"
                },
                "object": {
                    "key": "some-key/more-key/filteringText/additionaldata.png"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to keep the messages if only **filteringText** is present in *key* field.

**Note**: The entire message is sent as text by S3 notification service, so Records is not a json object but string.

Comment: SNS subscription filters operate on [Message Attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMessageAttributes.html), not the body payload.  You'll need a different solution, possibly involving Lambda, to categorize the messages emitted by S3 events.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Yes, having a Lambda in between that does the filtering seems like the only solution at the moment.

Comment: I accomplished this with S3 > Lambda > SNS. The Lambda function re-publishes the event to SNS with message attributes populated with various things extracted from the event.  My object keys look like `one/two/three/four/.../n` and the interesting values to SNS filters are the bucket name, and substrings `three` and/or `n` so I extract those by splitting the key and put them into the message attributes.  Topic subscriptions filter on some or all of these.

Comment: But if I am using the Lambda, shouldn't the filtering be handled in the Lambda itself?
Wouldn't that be more efficient than making the Lambda process every message to create message attributes to filter by the SNS?

Comment: If your topic only has one subscriber, or if all subscribers want the same subset of events, then yes, you could and probably should just filter the messages in Lambda.  In my case, I have an unspecified/unlimited number of potential subscribers, each of which wants to see only events with one specific value in that third path element.

Comment: Yea, my case had all the subscribers wanting the same set of messages. Else, your solution seems a correct way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I've seen in the documentation, you can't do regex matches or substrings, but you can match prefixes and create your own attributes in the MessageAttributes field.

To do this, I send the S3 event to a simple Lambda that adds MessageAttributes and then sends to SNS.

In effect, S3 -> Lambda -> SNS -> other consumers (with filtering).

The Lambda can do something like this (where you'll have to programmatically decide when to add the attribute):

```
let messageAttributes = {
                    myfilterkey: {DataType: "String", StringValue:"filteringText"}
                };
let params = {
                    Message: JSON.stringify(payload),
                    MessageAttributes: messageAttributes,
                    MessageStructure: 'json',
                    TargetArn: SNS_ARN
                };
await sns.publish(params).promise();
```

Then in SNS you can filter:

```
{"myfilterkey": ["filtertext"]}
```

It seems a little convoluted to put the Lambda in there, but I like the idea of being able to plug and unplug consumers from SNS on the fly and use filtering to determine who gets what.

Comment: If I use a Lambda, wouldn't it be right to filter the messages in the Lambda itself than to add a custom prefix and let the SNS handle the filtration?

Comment: You can certainly do filtering in the Lambda, but it keeps the Lambda simpler to just add the MessageAttributes and send to SNS. Once it's in SNS, I can add, remove, or change filtering criteria per consumer without changing any Lambda code or causing downtime to other consumers. It depends on what you anticipate future growth will look like.

Comment: Makes sense. But I think @Michael-sqlbot's comment above is more of the reason why filtering should be handled by SNS.